# Página da Web expirada quando volto à pagina pelo botao do navegador. Pagina anterior c/ postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

Na minha aplicação atual, possuo uma página de lista de conteúdos, o qual tem um pequeno formulário acima para efetuar "filtros" na GridView abaixo para aí sim selecionar um item e ir a próxima pagina editar o mesmo.

O que acontece é que quando estou na página de edição e tento voltar para pagina de listagem pelo botão do navegador, apresenta "Página de Web Expirada"(somente quando selecionei algum filtro a pagina de listagem).

Já tentei usar o código abaixo, para tentar interceptar o load e forçar um recarregar da página sem os valores mesmo mas sem sucesso.

```
    private void Page_PreRender(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack && !Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath.Contains("origem-listar.aspx"))
        {
            Response.Write("<html><head><script>location.replace('" + Request.Url + "');\n" + "</script></head><body></body></html>\n");
            Response.End();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Esse é o comportamento normal do navegador. Todas as páginas que foram obtidas por um pedido POST expiram. Nem chegam ao servidor, pelo que a solução que usaste não funciona. É um sistema de proteção.

Comment: Há como pelo menos mudar à pagina "passada" ? pensei pois no meu sistema muitos usuários são costumados a clicar no botão voltar do navegador e não do botão voltar da pagina. Pelo menos disparar um alerta "Você não pode voltar por aqui, use o botão voltar na página."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realmente, ao voltar para uma página que foi gerada através de informações enviadas via `POST`, o browser pode dizer que a página expirou, ou dizer que irá submeter as informações novamente, o que pode nem sempre ser o desejado.

Não há uma forma garantida para desabilitar o botão "voltar" dos browsers. Contudo, se o sistema não precisar ser executado no IE 9-, é possível utilizar a API para manipular o histórico do browser, e com isso fazer uma espécie de *gambiarra*. A API funciona em Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera ou IE 10+.

- [Manipulating the browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)
- [Window.onpopstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onpopstate)

Exemplo de código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>
        Título
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        history.pushState({page: 1}, "Título", "#");
        window.addEventListener("popstate", function(event) {
            history.pushState({page: 1}, "Título", "#");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

A *gambiarra* consiste em criar um loop infinito no histórico do browser, de modo que o botão "voltar" acaba sempre voltando para a mesma página (que é a página atual).

- Detalhe: Essa técnica fará com que a URL atual tenha acrescido à ela o caractere `#`.
- Detalhe 2: Dependendo de quantas vezes o usuário for redirecionado para essa página, e de como o sistema é utilizado, pode ser que o histórico venha a crescer bastante.
- Detalhe 3: Teste o comportamento para ver se ele não irá atrapalhar seu sistema.

*Baseado nessa [resposta do SO en](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23794555/3569421).